# Level sets of harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $h=u+iv: U \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function and $h^{´}(z)\neq 0 \forall z\in U$ and $U$ open. Show that the trajectories of the gradient vector field are the connected components of the level sets of v. This should be implied by the Cauchy Riemannsch differential equations, but I don´t see how.

Comment: I usually could solve this but my brain is kind of frozen. Maybe I can come back later if I come up with anything.

Comment: Since you write $h'(z)$ and mention the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I suppose that $h$ shall in fact be holomorphic, not only harmonic?

Comment: Hints: It suffices to prove the level curves of $u$ are everywhere orthogonal to the level curves of $v$, and the complex derivative of $h$ is locally a conformal (angle-preserving) mapping of the plane thanks to Cauchy-Riemann.

Comment: Yes I fixed it, h is a holomorphic function.